# Django graphene, filtering by object

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-django

Now my filter looks like this

```
class Document(graphene.ObjectType):

    number = graphene.relay.ConnectionField(
        ReportDocumentNumberConnection,
        doc__number__in=graphene.List(graphene.String, required=False),
        doc__supplier__delivery__in=graphene.List(graphene.String, required=False),
        doc__supplier__number__in=graphene.List(graphene.String, required=False),
    )
```

And it works fine with Query like this

```
{
  allDocuments{

    number(doc_Number_In: "TVF" doc_Supplier_Delivery_In: "Q23") { ... }
  }
}
```

But I want to put all my filters into one object, something like this

```
{
  allDocuments{

    number(inputFilter: {doc_Number_In: "TVF" doc_Supplier_Delivery_In: "Q23"}) { ... }
  }
}
```

Is that possible? If yes, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try `graphene.types.generic.GenericScalar()`

```py
from graphene.types.generic import GenericScalar


class Document(graphene.ObjectType):

    number = GenericScalar()
```

https://medium.com/open-graphql/jsonfield-models-in-graphene-django-308ae43d14ee

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.